# WPF WindowState programmatic

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I did my own titlebar on a WPF-window and on the right side I placed three buttons for "minimize", "maximize" and "close".
For the maximize function I wrote this:

```
static bool isMaximized = false;

private void btnMaximize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(isMaximized == false)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            isMaximized = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Height = 350;
            Width = 525;
            isMaximized = false;
        }
    }
```

So, the window will be maximized but it will not restored to his original size if I click the button again. What I do wrong?

Thank you for helping,
Filippo.

Comment: You're not setting it back to `WindowState.Normal`, as far as I can see.

Comment: That's right. Thank you.